# How can I name a namespace dedicated to span just classes holding exclusively static fields?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, conventions

For example, is it a good practice to call this namespaces as `Utilities` or `Constants` etc. Or the `Utilities` are that kind of classes that hold static methods as well ?

```
namespace ExempleSolution.ExampleProj.Utilities
{
    // A class for AVOIDING MAGIC STRINGS within my project (not solution)
    public class BundlePath
    {
        public const string Jquery = "~/bundles/jquery";
        public const string CustomStyles = "~/bundles/customStyles";
        public const string CustomScripts = "~/bundles/customScripts";
        // etc.
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I'm just curious what your opinion is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like something that should be in a **Common** library. The **Utilities** modules I run into typically contain helper methods and classes that are useful across the board, whereas **Common** typically contains things that have no dependencies but that other projects typically want to know about - enums, magic int/string values, interfaces, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Now I've realzied that **Utilities** describe classes that contain _static methods_  and **do not necessarily** consist of only static fields.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'ld like to point out that this question has no one correct answer. It's a matter of opinion and as such, not suited for Stackoverflow.
However, I personally believe that event opinion based questions deserves an answer - so here:

Such classes are usually a part of a bigger project. If that is the case, I like to add the project's main namespace before - for example, `MyProject.Utitities`.

If they are general utilities you are using in more then one project, you can simply call them `Utilities`, or `Andrey.Utilities`.

IMHO, the name `Constants` is usually not a good fit for a namespace, as usually you will have only one class for constants per project.